# Raid 10 data failure

Tags: raid

If I have 16 drives in a RAID 10, how many drives would I have to drop to have data loss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that many drives I would use RAID 60. With RAID 10 you're vulnerable in different ways depending on which drive(s) fail.

[image: ss of raid10]

In this scenario if you lose the 2 disks that share a common block (D1, D2, etc.) you're hosed. For your situation given you have 16 drives you have basically 8 groups of disks.

So you can lose 1 disk from each group and still be fine. If you lose 2 disks that are part of the same group (mirror) then you're out of luck.

#### References

- [RAID Disk Space Calculator](https://www.icc-usa.com/raid-calculator)
- [RAID 10 Vs RAID 01 (RAID 1+0 Vs RAID 0+1) Explained with Diagram](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/raid10-vs-raid01/)

Answer (score 4):

The array becomes unrecoverable when losing both pairs in the same mirror. If you're very unlucky, this means two disks can cause a failure. If you are very lucky, you can lose up to 8 without a failure.